# Clear content after <i> element

Tags: css

I want to be able to clear the content in a '< td >' after a certain class (sprite-empos) and wonder if there is any way without adding any new classes or using js (what I've tried below is not working)?

To clearify it's '985' I want to be removed in a certain viewport, but not the '< i >' element.

I know the best way should be to wrap the content in an element and apply a class to it, but by several reasons this is not possible.

```
<td rowspan="2">
    <p><i class="sprite-io sprite-empos"></i> 985</p>
</td>

.sprite-empos:after {
    content:" "; // <---- not working
}
```

Comment: This cannot be done with only CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you well... you want to hide the text after the icon with CSS?
Maybe apply 'font-size: 0px' to the td?

Comment: Nice creative solution!

Comment: I wouldnt do that if i were you. icons are resized with attribute font-size. So if you put that, icon will also disappear.. Have you checked what you posted as answer actually works?

Comment: I actually use that for my projects and the icon does not disappear. I will check again in case there's another attribute that avoids it.
Another solution could be 'color: transparent'.

Comment: @Matthew : Exactly... if you remove the font-size declaration for .sprite-io, icon will disappear.. Also everything in <p> tag will have no text according to your solution. Just that this is not a neat solution as this would mean over-riding all styles of icons. :)..

Comment: @Roy M J It depends on how is loaded the icon. If you set the icon with css classes and 'background-image', then font-size won't affect it :D This is how Bootstrap does it for example, and seems to be a similar case in the question.